# Highcharts Gauge: Exporting Dynamic Labels - dynamic series values export but not dynamic text

Tags: javascript, dynamic, highcharts, export, gauge

I've created a Highcharts temperature gauge that dynamically updates the daily maximum, daily minimum and current temperatures. Every 5 minutes, a CSV is generated on my network drive based on current conditions measured at this station. This CSV has one row and four columns of data in this order left to right: timestamp, daily max, daily min and current temps. I have three series coded for each temperature measurement, and I use jQuery to get my CSV data values, construct an array, then pass those values to their proper Highcharts series every three seconds. This code works great for that, the needles change without refreshing the page every five minutes when new CSV values are generated, and they display properly on exported images. I also have a label positioned atop the gauge that updates and displays the timestamp from my CSV on the webpage using the same jQuery array.

The issue I'm attempting to solve is getting my dynamic timestamp label to display on exported images. The timestamp displays with the gauge on the webpage, it updates perfectly fine without refreshing the page, however the timestamp does not display on exported images. What I need is to have the dynamic timestamp display on the exported images of this gauge. Please let me know if you've encountered this before and/or have any suggestions on how to fix this issue.

Here is a sample of my code. Please note that this code in its current state causes the text 'Timestamp 2' to display on the exported image where I want the most current timestamp to display.

```
<script defer type="text/javascript">

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        name: 'Temp',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        margin: [50, 50, 50, 50],
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false,
        height: 500,
        events: {
            load: function() {
                this.renderer.image('file location of this image', (((this.chartWidth / 2) - (this.plotHeight / 2)) + ((0.1062495 - (this.plotHeight * 0.0000245825)) * this.plotHeight)), //! x-coordinate
                (((this.chartHeight / 2) - (this.plotHeight / 2)) + ((0.1062495 - (this.plotHeight * 0.0000245825)) * this.plotHeight)), //! y-coordinate
                (this.plotHeight - ((0.212499 - (this.plotHeight * 0.000049165)) * this.plotHeight)), //!width
                (this.plotHeight - ((0.212499 - (this.plotHeight * 0.000049165)) * this.plotHeight))) //!height
                .attr({}).css({}).add();

                this.renderer.text('text goes here', ((this.chartWidth - this.plotWidth) / 2), this.chartHeight - ((this.chartHeight - this.plotHeight) / 2) + 20).attr({}).css({
                    color: '#0000aa'
                }).add();

                this.renderer.text('text goes here', ((this.chartWidth - this.plotWidth) / 2), this.chartHeight - (this.chartHeight - this.plotHeight) / 2).attr({}).css({}).add();

                this.myLabel = this.renderer.text(['Timestamp'], ((this.chartWidth - this.plotWidth) / 2), ((this.chartHeight - this.plotHeight) / 2) + 20).attr({}).css({}).add();
            },
        }
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Temperature'
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: -150,
        endAngle: 150,
        background: {
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            borderColor: 'transparent',
        },
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        min: -70,
        max: 120,

        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        minorTickWidth: 1,
        minorTickLength: 10,
        minorTickPosition: 'inside',
        minorTickColor: '#666',
        tickPixelInterval: 30,
        tickWidth: 2,

        tickPositions: [ - 70, -60, -50, -40, -30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120],

        tickPosition: 'inside',
        tickLength: 10,
        tickColor: '#666',

        labels: {
            step: 1,
            rotation: 'auto'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Deg F'
        },

        plotBands: [{

            from: -70,
            to: -40,
            color: '#FFFFFF' // white
        },
        {

            from: -40,
            to: 0,
            color: '#f633ff' // green
        },
        {

            from: 0,
            to: 32,
            color: '#0D0DDF' // blue
        },
        {

            from: 32,
            to: 80,
            color: '#55BF3B' // yellow
        },
        {

            from: 70,
            to: 100,
            color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
        },
        {

            from: 100,
            to: 120,
            color: '#DF5353' // red
        }]
    },

    exporting: {
        allowHTML: true,
        sourceWidth: 1000,
        sourceHeight: 1000,
        chartOptions: {
            chart: {
                events: {
                    load: function() {
                        this.renderer.image('file location of this image', (((this.chartWidth / 2) - (this.plotHeight / 2)) + ((0.1062495 - (this.plotHeight * 0.0000245825)) * this.plotHeight)), //! x-coordinate
                        (((this.chartHeight / 2) - (this.plotHeight / 2)) + ((0.1062495 - (this.plotHeight * 0.0000245825)) * this.plotHeight)), //! y-coordinate
                        (this.plotHeight - ((0.212499 - (this.plotHeight * 0.000049165)) * this.plotHeight)), //!width
                        (this.plotHeight - ((0.212499 - (this.plotHeight * 0.000049165)) * this.plotHeight))) //!height
                        .attr({}).css({}).add();

                        this.renderer.text('text goes here', ((this.chartWidth - this.plotWidth) / 2), this.chartHeight - ((this.chartHeight - this.plotHeight) / 2) + 20).attr({}).css({
                            color: '#0000aa'
                        }).add();

                        this.renderer.text('text goes here', ((this.chartWidth - this.plotWidth) / 2), this.chartHeight - (this.chartHeight - this.plotHeight) / 2).attr({}).css({}).add();

                        this.myLabel = this.renderer.text(['Timestamp 2'], ((this.chartWidth - this.plotWidth) / 2), ((this.chartHeight - this.plotHeight) / 2) + 20).attr({}).css({}).add();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'gauge',
        name: 'Current Temp',
        color: 'black',
        data: [0],
        dial: {
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 0,
            baseWidth: 3,
            topWidth: 1,
            rearLength: '0%'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' Deg F'
        }
    },
    {
        type: 'gauge',
        name: 'Daily Max Temp',
        color: 'red',
        data: [0],
        dial: {
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 0,
            baseWidth: 1,
            topWidth: 1,
            rearLength: '0%'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' Deg F'
        }
    },
    {
        type: 'gauge',
        name: 'Daily Min Temp',
        color: 'blue',
        data: [0],
        dial: {
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            borderWidth: 0,
            baseWidth: 1,
            topWidth: 1,
            rearLength: '0%'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' Deg F'
        }
    }]
},

function(chart) {
    if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
        setInterval(function() {
            var pointcurrent = chart.series[0].points[0];
            var pointmax = chart.series[1].points[0];
            var pointmin = chart.series[2].points[0];

            jQuery.get('file location of my CSV',
            function(data) {
                const dataarray = data.split(",");
                pointcurrent.update(parseFloat(dataarray[4]));
                pointmax.update(parseFloat(dataarray[1]));
                pointmin.update(parseFloat(dataarray[2]));
                chart.myLabel.attr({
                    text: dataarray[0]
                });
            });
        },
        3000);
    }
},
);
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I was expecting the dynamic timestamp label to display on exported images of the gauge. The correct timestamp displays just fine on the gauge in a web browser, however that same timestamp does not display on exported images. Dynamic series data updates and displays just fine with this code.

Answer (score 0):

For this configuration, you can export the actual time stamp during export to images, Is that solution you are looking for?

```
document.getElementById('export').addEventListener('click', function() {
  timeStamp = chart.time.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', Date.now());
  chart.exportChartLocal({
    type: 'application/pdf',
    width: 600,
  }, {
    title: {
      text: 'It works'
    },
  });
})
```

You can also define time as a separate instance:

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Time

```
events: {
  load: function() {
    const time = new Highcharts.Time();
    const timeStamp = time.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', Date.now());

    this.myLabel = this.renderer.text(timeStamp, ((this.chartWidth - this.plotWidth) / 2), ((this.chartHeight - this.plotHeight) / 2) + 20).attr({}).css({}).add();
  },
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mbocn91h/

Comment: Thank you for responding and providing this code! However, for accuracy purposes, I would like the timestamp to represent the time at which the measurements were taken, not necessarily the time at which an exported image was downloaded.

Comment: Instead `events.load()` it's options to change to `events.redraw()` and during click (measure) involve this, see [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mbocn91h/1/).

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to get the timestamp from when my temperature measurements were taken to display on exported images, but not without adding an "alert" line of code. This is a dirty fix that isn't user friendly for my end users since they'll get an alert every time they go to export the chart. Does anyone happen to know a work-around for this, or why an alert allows for dynamic timestamps to be displayed on exported images? Without the "alert(datetime3)" line of code, this dynamic timestamp does not display on exported images.

Here is the updated code:

```
let chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        name: 'Temp',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        margin: [50,50,50,50],
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false,
        height: 500,
        animation: {
            duration: 0
        },
        events: {
             load: function() {
                this.renderer.image('file location of this image here', 
                    (((this.chartWidth / 2) - (this.plotHeight / 2)) + ((0.1062495 - (this.plotHeight * 0.0000245825)) * this.plotHeight)), //! x-coordinate
                    (((this.chartHeight / 2) - (this.plotHeight / 2)) + ((0.1062495 - (this.plotHeight * 0.0000245825)) * this.plotHeight)), //! y-coordinate
                    (this.plotHeight - ((0.212499 - (this.plotHeight * 0.000049165)) * this.plotHeight)), //!width
                    (this.plotHeight - ((0.212499 - (this.plotHeight * 0.000049165)) * this.plotHeight))) //!height
                    .attr({})
                    .css({})
                    .add();

                 this.renderer.text('text goes here', ((this.chartWidth - this.plotWidth) / 2), this.chartHeight - ((this.chartHeight - this.plotHeight) / 2) + 20)
                    .attr({})
                    .css({color: '#0000aa'})
                    .add();

                 this.renderer.text('text goes here', ((this.chartWidth - this.plotWidth) / 2), this.chartHeight - (this.chartHeight - this.plotHeight) / 2)
                    .attr({})
                    .css({})
                    .add();
                
                jQuery.get('file location of my CSV here', function(data) {
                    let months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
                    const dataarray1 = data.split(",");
                    chart.myLabel.attr({text: dataarray1[0]}, Date.parse(dataarray1[0]));
                    var datetime1 = Date.parse([dataarray1[0]]);
                    var month = new Date (datetime1).getMonth();
                    var day = new Date (datetime1).getDate();
                    var mon = months[month];
                    var year = new Date (datetime1).getFullYear();
                    var hour = new Date (datetime1).getHours();
                    var min = new Date (datetime1).getMinutes();
                    min = min < 10 ? '0' + min : min;
                    hour = hour < 10 ? '0' + hour : hour;
                    day = day < 10 ? '0' + day : day;

                    chart.myLabel.attr({text: [day + ' ' + mon + ' ' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + min]});
                });
    
                this.myLabel = this.renderer.text([], ((this.chartWidth - this.plotWidth) / 2), ((this.chartHeight - this.plotHeight) / 2) + 20)
                    .attr({})
                    .css({})
                    .add();
                        }
                }
        },

        title: {
                text: 'Temperature'
        },

        pane: {
                startAngle: -150,
                endAngle: 150,
                background: {
                         backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                         borderColor: 'transparent',
                },
        },

        // the value axis
        yAxis: {
                min: -70,
                max: 120,
                minorTickInterval: 'auto',
                minorTickWidth: 1,
                minorTickLength: 10,
                minorTickPosition: 'inside',
                minorTickColor: '#666',
                tickPixelInterval: 30,
                tickWidth: 2,
                tickPositions: [-70, -60, -50, -40, -30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120],
                tickPosition: 'inside',
                tickLength: 10,
                tickColor: '#666',

                labels: {
                        step: 1,
                        rotation: 'auto'
                },

                title: {
                        text: 'Deg F'
                },

                plotBands: [{
                        from: -70,
                        to: -40,
                        color: '#FFFFFF' // white
                }, {
                        from: -40,
                        to: 0,
                        color: '#f633ff' // green
                }, {
                        from: 0,
                        to: 32,
                        color: '#0D0DDF' // blue
                }, {
                        from: 32,
                        to: 80,
                        color: '#55BF3B' // yellow
                }, {
                        from: 70,
                        to: 100,
                        color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
                }, {
                        from: 100,
                        to: 120,
                        color: '#DF5353' // red
                }]
        },

    exporting: {
        enabled: true,
        allowHTML: true,
        sourceWidth: 1000,
        sourceHeight: 1000,
        chartOptions: {
        chart: {
        events: {
            load: function (chart) {
                this.renderer.image('file location of this image here',
                    (((this.chartWidth / 2) - (this.plotHeight / 2)) + ((0.1062495 - (this.plotHeight * 0.0000245825)) * this.plotHeight)), //! x-coordinate
                    (((this.chartHeight / 2) - (this.plotHeight / 2)) + ((0.1062495 - (this.plotHeight * 0.0000245825)) * this.plotHeight)), //! y-coordinate
                    (this.plotHeight - ((0.212499 - (this.plotHeight * 0.000049165)) * this.plotHeight)), //!width
                    (this.plotHeight - ((0.212499 - (this.plotHeight * 0.000049165)) * this.plotHeight))) //!height
                        .attr({})
                        .css({})
                        .add();

                    this.renderer.text('text goes here', ((this.chartWidth - this.plotWidth) / 2), this.chartHeight - ((this.chartHeight - this.plotHeight) / 2) + 20)
                        .attr({})
                        .css({color: '#0000aa'})
                        .add();

                    this.renderer.text('text goes here', ((this.chartWidth - this.plotWidth) / 2), this.chartHeight - (this.chartHeight - this.plotHeight) / 2)
                        .attr({})
                        .css({})
                        .add();

                    var datetime3 = 'This Text Works';
                    jQuery.get('file location of my CSV here', function(data) {
                        const dataarray3 = data.split(",");
                        datetime3 = (dataarray3[0]);
                        chart.myLabel.attr({text: dataarray3[0]});
                    });
alert(datetime3);
                    this.myLabel = this.renderer.text([datetime3], ((this.chartWidth - this.plotWidth) / 2), ((this.chartHeight - this.plotHeight) / 2) + 20)
                        .attr({})
                        .css({})
                        .add();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'gauge',
        name: 'Current Temp',
        color: 'black',
        data: [0],
        dial: {
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 0,
            baseWidth: 3,
            topWidth: 1,
            rearLength:'0%'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' Deg F'
        }
    }, {
        type: 'gauge',
        name: 'Daily Max Temp',
        color: 'red',
        data: [0],
        dial: {
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 0,
            baseWidth: 1,
            topWidth: 1,
            rearLength:'0%'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' Deg F'
        }
    }, {
        type: 'gauge',
        name: 'Daily Min Temp',
        color: 'blue',
        data: [0],
        dial: {
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            borderWidth: 0,
            baseWidth: 1,
            topWidth: 1,
            rearLength:'0%'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' Deg F'
        }
    }]
},

function (chart) {
    if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
        setInterval(function () {
            var pointcurrent = chart.series[0].points[0];
            var pointmax = chart.series[1].points[0];
            var pointmin = chart.series[2].points[0];
            
            jQuery.get('file location of my CSV here',function(data) {
                let months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
                const dataarray2 = data.split(",");
                chart.myLabel.attr({text: dataarray2[0]}, Date.parse(dataarray2[0]));
                var datetime2 = Date.parse([dataarray2[0]]);
                var month = new Date (datetime2).getMonth();
                var day = new Date (datetime2).getDate();
                var mon = months[month];
                var year = new Date (datetime2).getFullYear();
                var hour = new Date (datetime2).getHours();
                var min = new Date (datetime2).getMinutes();
                min = min < 10 ? '0' + min : min;
                hour = hour < 10 ? '0' + hour : hour;
                day = day < 10 ? '0' + day : day;

                chart.myLabel.attr({text: [day + ' ' + mon + ' ' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + min]});
            
                pointcurrent.update (parseFloat(dataarray2[4]));
                pointmax.update (parseFloat(dataarray2[1]));
                pointmin.update (parseFloat(dataarray2[2]));
            });
        }, 3000);
    }
},
);
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```